# Is there an equivalent to <jsp:include in PHP that can also handle parameters and default values

Tags: php, jsp, include

I have a PHP page that lists many products that each consist of HTML that -depending on the product- does or does not show certain information. I extracted this "product HTML" into a separate PHP file that I include many times. The external file uses variables for each of the product's attributes and also `if` statements so that parts of the HTML are not rendered at all when an attribute is not set.

The problem is that many of the attributes have default values that I do not want to set each time I call the include

So is there a mechanism in PHP that lets me include another PHP file in such a way that:

1. I can provide parameters to the file,
2. uses a default value for the parameters when I do not provide a value,
3. can be used multiple times in one file.

(This is the way `<jsp:include` works.)

Keep in mind that I cannot use simple variables (as far as I know) because they keep their value between two separate include calls.

Comment: Whenever you include any file in PHP, all variables defined in existing(current) script will be available to included PHP file, like wise if you declare some variables in included file, it will be available in further executing in your current script. So, you can use all `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` arrays within both scripts (current & included).

Comment: Yes, but if you read my remark at the end that does not work for me because it does not allow me to define variables. This is because the variables keep their value in between two includes on the same page

Comment: Never tried in-depth, but I always used to declare some globally used variable in my `config.php` and include it in almost all other script. There *I'm able to access those variables*.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know if I should use the default value or the set value. This is because I cannot differentiate between a newly set value for a variable and the value of that variable for the previous product. I could of course clear all values in between consecutive include calls, but then I might as well fill in all the variables, which is what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: What about wrapping the "product HTML" in a function and using default parameter values?

Comment: Is this like what JohnKiller proposed below?

Comment: Yes, but instead of using an Array and the `extract` function you could introduce an argument for each option (using [`default arguments`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) when needed). This way it becomes immediately clear which options are available for generating the HTML.

Comment: or better, use a framework like CodeIgniter or any MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include a file in PHP, that file has access to the current scope. So, we need a "clean" scope with no variables and populate the one we need. The best way to go is using a function and the PHP extract method:

```
function product($data){
    extract($data);
    require(....path to file);
}
```

Now call it:

```
product(array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    ....
));
```

This way, on the included file you got a $foo variable with 'bar' value and nothing else. This is how MVC frameworks deal with views.

Edit:

```
<?PHP
function product($data){
    extract($data);
?>
    <HTML content>
<?PHP
}
?>
```

Now "require_once" the file with this and call it like before.

Comment: So, I guess there is no 'native' PHP way of doing this? I need to create this function to create the additional scope?

Comment: Yes. When you include a php file, it can have multiple things inside: code, functions, classes etc... so it's not like calling a function!

Comment: Is there a way to put both the function and the HTML in the external file so I only have to call the function from my main page?